# Утечка памяти LeakCanary, recyclerView, adapter

Tags: android, recyclerview, утечка-памяти, recyclerview.adapter

Подскажите в чем может быть ошибка в адаптере или в чем может быть ошибка, вызывающая такие утечки памяти

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class ImageListAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageListAdapter.ImageListViewHolder> {

private List<Item> images = new ArrayList<>();
@Inject
Picasso builder;

public ImageListAdapter() {
    MyApplication.getsApplicationComponent().inject(this);
}

@Override
public ImageListAdapter.ImageListViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ImageListViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_item, null));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ImageListAdapter.ImageListViewHolder holder, int position) {
    builder.load(images.get(position).getPreview())
            .fit().centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_image_icon)
            .error(R.drawable.fail)
            .into(holder.imageView);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(images==null)
        return 0;
    return images.size();
}

public void addAll(List<Item> list) {
    images.addAll(list);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clear() {
    images.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public Item getItem(int position){
    return images.get(position);
}

public class ImageListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.imageViewItem)
    ImageView imageView;

    public ImageListViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Для начала можете попробовать сделать класс ImageListViewHolder - статическим. + Не вижу смысла использовать ButterKnife чтоб забиндить всего одну вьюху ...

Comment: Очень похоже что проблема не в самом коде адаптера, а в том как вы его используете во внешнем коде. + каждый раз в `onBindViewHolder` обрабатывать картинки мне кажется лишним. Если это делать до вызова `addAll`, то можно избавиться от DI и зависимости от Picasso.

Comment: в Di мб. Покажите модуль, где провайдится Picasso, скорей всего ликайте Activity context.